# How to run a GitHub action step only once on pull request

Tags: github-actions

I want to run a certain step of GitHub actions workflow to run only once per pull request. The workflow is already limited to running only on PR, but it will rerun every time a new commit is made to it. This is as expected, but I want a certain step to run only once. Or even better - exactly once. For example when I send a notification that a new PR was opened, this should happen only/exactly once to prevent spam.

So I would expect some kind of condition on the step e.g.:

```
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  my-job:
    steps:
      - name: Runs only once
        # what condition to put here?
        if: ??
        run: echo "Only one"
```

I know about the option to run the workflow only on opening the pull request like:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
```

But can I evaluate the same condition on a step?

Comment: So the correct condition like implied from the other post is `if: ${{ github.event.action == 'opened' }}`